# How to load and display an image in OpenGL ES 3.0 using C++

Tags: textures, opengl-es, image

I'm trying to make a simple app on Android Studio using the NDK, JNI to call C++ code that load and display an image. I have managed to create the surface and draw a simple Triangle already.

Now, I'm looking for a way to load and display an image in OpenGL ES 3.0 using C++. I have done the search around but all of them is either missing some important function or written in Java. It would be great if someone could guide me with a simple example, thanks in advanced :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shaders you need to define a new uniform variable with the type "sampler2D"

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;
```

Now, you need to somehow load an image into a byte array. After you created this, you create a new opengl texture object using `glGenTextures`. You bind it with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &textureId)`.

You need to load in the data to the texture object with [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

After this you pretty much have the texture in the GPU. Now you need to bind it again, but now you need to specify in which texture slot you want to put it in. These are marked with the `GL_TEXTUREX` constants, where X is the slot id. Depending on the OpenGL version, there's either 8, 16 or 32 possible slots.

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &textureId);
```

After everything is bound, you load the uniform sampler. You need to load in the slot id you put the texture in as an integer:

```
// samplerLoc is the location returned by glGetUniformLocation
// You should save this somewhere
glUniform1i(&samplerLoc, 0);
```

And in the shader you can sample the texture with

```
vec4 color = texture2D(sampler, textureCoords);
```

(If the model doesn't have texture coordinates, then you need to add that the same way you added vertex coordinates)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's quite simple and easy to understand to me. Btw, may i ask which function should i use to " load an image into a byte array" ? And It would be great if you could quote the whole process from loading the image to drawing it. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Toan To be honest, I'm not a c++ guy and I don't really know how to use IO in it.

Comment: thank you anyway, I got the concept how to do it now. I'm going to have a look around for more detail, have a nice day :).